# What do you call a subtree covering a subset of contiguous leaves?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, trees

In the data structure field, what is the (best) term used to identify (designate) a subtree covering a subset of contiguous leaves?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to mean a subtree obtained by taking a certain node and all its successors.

In data structures, the implicit assumption usually is that we consider *rooted* (and often *ordered*) trees. Therefore, "subtree" is usually taken to mean what you intend; "subtree" as in graph-theoretic "subgraph" is rarely used (in my experience).

If you want to make very clear what you mean, you can write

> The subtree of $T$ which is rooted in $x \in T$.

A common notation for this tree is $T_x$.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I asked in the comments (now deleted); the OP said they wanted what I state in the first paragraph. You answer follows another reasonable interpretation of the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is the subtree rooted at the *least common ancestor* of the set of leaves (the fact that the leaves are continuous makes no difference). I'm not sure there is any shorter term.